# Angular Digest cycle does not fire in Protractor test

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, protractor

Whenever I run my protractor test Angular is not evaluating its expressions.  Below is a screenshot I caught while running my protractor test.

[image]

I have tried a `browser.waitForAngular()` but it didn't work.  I'm not sure why this is happening.  Does anybody know why this is the case?

Thanks.

EDIT:

This actually works fine when I manually test it with `ionic serve` but breaks when I run my protractor test.

Comment: Do you pull up a server when you start your tests? If so, if you run the server standalone, does it still gives the same error?

Comment: Yes, I pull up a server when I start my tests.  The application works when I do manual testing with the server but when protractor pulls up the browser it does not link up with Angular for whatever reason.

Comment: then the problem is in the way you are pulling up the server and not with protractor. Protractor has no influence on a server.